# Windows Service with Service Layer

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, windows-services, business-logic

Please advise on the following:

Context:

I have a windows service, with a service and data layer. Now my service needs to watch a folder for files and then if there are files matching a particular regex, it should load the files into the database and move the file to a 'Complete' folder.

Question:

What code should go in the Windows Service ... and what code should go into the Service Layer. My initials thoughts was to do all the loading of the file in the Service Layer while putting all the file watching and file moving capabalities in the Windows Service.

Please advise . . . Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

Service layer:

- watching for file
- read file content
- submit data to data layer
- moving file to complete folder

Data layer:

- verify data
- store data

This is the simplest case (remember KISS).

If you need the logic for processing  the file elsewhere you can add a third domain service layer.

Service layer:

- watch for file
- invoke domain service layer

Domain service layer:

- read file content
- submit data to data layer
- move file to complete folder

Data layer:

- verify data
- store data

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So does that mean the Windows service itself should just pass through requests to the service layer and not do any processing itself? Currently, the Windows Service is watching for the file and doing the file moving.

Comment: The Windows service should watch for file and pass the filename to domain service layer. Domain service layer does the rest of the work (read content, submit data to data layer and move file). If you use this approach the windows service is very slim and you can reuse the processing logic elsewhere (e.g. Client, WebService etc.)